# Find first occurrence of a substring from a dictionary of substrings within each value of a pandas series and insert corresponding dictionary value

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

`myDict= {'is':'A', 'th':'B', 'ro':'C'}`

and the following Pandas dataframe with a single column of strings (no index):

```
checkColumn

This is the first row
Here is the second row
Row three is here
And another row is here
```

I want to create a second column that assigns the value from the dictionary whose key appears first in each string. So the result I'm looking for is:

```
checkColumn                         labelAssignment

This is the first row               B
Here is the second row              A
Row three is here                   C
And another row is here             B
```

A few parameters:
- More than one key can appear in each string. For example, in the third row, all three keys appear, but it is assigned C since 'ro' appears first.
- The substrings can be parts of words, so splitting the string up into individual words and checking those won't work.
- I need it to be case-insensitive, so that 'ro' matches 'Row'.
- If a key is not found, either np.nan or a blank string can be given.

Almost all of the answers on SO that I've found so far address either (a) finding the first value of a series, and not the first substring from within each value of that series, or (b) the first occurrence of a substring within a string, without applying it to a pandas dataframe. [For example, this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38334997/5451009) shows how to check if a key in a dictionary is contained in a string, but because this is pandas I shouldn't use the `for` loops and the list comprehension returns a list, which I don't want...I want to return the value itself.

The pseudocode I have in mind uses np.where:

```
df['labelAssignment'] = np.where(check for first occurrence of myDict key in df.checkColumn, corresponding value from myDict, '')
```

But how do I form the syntax for that np.where statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the system, you might want to use `OrderedDict` to guarantee the given dictionary order. But you can do something like this:

```
(df.checkColumn
   .str.lower()
   .str.extract("({:})".format('|'.join(myDict.keys())) )[0]
   .map(myDict)
)
```

Output:

```
0    B
1    A
2    C
3    B
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! But would you mind walking me through what the `extract` portion is doing, exactly?

Comment: After reading the Pandas documentation on `str.extract` (here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), I have a better idea now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For this logic, you'll need a row-wise apply. Start by searching `checkColumn` for the dict key, then sorting by lookup index to find the earliest appearance. Make sure to check if it doesn't appear at all:

```py
def label_for_check(row):
    check = row['checkColumn'] or ''
    index, lookup = sorted([(check.lower().find(k.lower()), k) for k in myDict.keys()])[0]
    return myDict[lookup] if index >= 0 else np.nan

df['labelAssignment'] = df.apply(label_for_check, axis=1)
```

```
               checkColumn labelAssignment
0    This is the first row               B
1   Here is the second row               A
2        Row three is here               C
3  And another row is here               B
4               nothing...             NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm getting the following error:
`AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'", 'occurred at index 193')`. I probably have some null values in the checkColumn, sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: You just need to check against `None`s in `checkColumn`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
myDict= {'is':'A', 'th':'B', 'ro':'C'}
rows=['This is the first row','Here is the second row','Row three is here','And another row is here']

df=pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=['checkColumn'])

df
```

**First Output**

```
    checkColumn
0   This is the first row
1   Here is the second row
2   Row three is here
3   And another row is here
```

Create one function

```
temp=[]
def checkrows(x):
    list1 = myDict.keys()
    temp=[]
    for item in list1:
        pattern=item
        match=re.search(pattern,x.lower())
        temp.append([match.start(),match.end()])

    temp.sort()
    return x[temp[0][0]:temp[0][1]].lower()

result=df.checkColumn.apply(lambda x: checkrows(x))

df['Label Assignment']=[myDict[item] for item in result]

df
```

**Final Output**

```
    checkColumn             Label Assignment
0   This is the first row        B
1   Here is the second row       A
2   Row three is here            C
3   And another row is here      B
```

Note: There can be many ways to shorten this code.

Thanks